# Why does discard() not work as expected?

Tags: java, forms, vaadin

I tried to build a Simple Form with an ComboBox and a reset button. I thought with discard I can reset the combobox. What have I done wrong? The uncommented combobox.select is a workaround.

Following the simple example:

```
public class VaadinprojectApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void init() {
    final Window mainWindow = new Window("Simpleform");

    final List<String> aListWithStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    aListWithStrings.add("Somthing");
    final BeanItemContainer<String> objects = new BeanItemContainer<String>(String.class, aListWithStrings);
    final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox("Importers", objects);

    // reset button
    final Button resetButton = new Button("Reset", new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(final ClickEvent event) {
            // comboBox.select(comboBox.getNullSelectionItemId());
            comboBox.discard();
            System.out.println("reset");
        }
    });
    final FormLayout form = new FormLayout();
    form.addComponent(comboBox);
    form.addComponent(resetButton);
    form.setSizeUndefined();

    mainWindow.addComponent(form);
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}
}
```

Comment: What is `ComboBox`? I can't find it in JavaDoc.

Comment: It is a Vaadin component. `com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox`

Answer (score 0):

In order to choose nothing in the combobox, use this instead of `discard()` :

```
comboBox.setValue(null);
```

Comment: Actually, that is also a solution like  `comboBox.select(comboBox.getNullSelectionItemId());` but it doesn't answer the question, why `discard()`not works.

Answer (score 0):

`final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox("Importers", objects);`

The Line above doesn't set the datasource properly. `discard()`checks if the datasource != null. But in the case of the code example the datasource is null and so nothing happends. Why? I don't know yet.